# Microsoft EAS Sync Command

Tags: exchange-server, activesync, wbxml

My initial request is

```
POST : /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?User=XXXX&DeviceId=XXX&DeviceType=XXX&Cmd=Sync

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<airsync:Sync xmlns:airsync="AirSync">
    <airsync:Collections>
        <airsync:Collection>
            <airsync:SyncKey>0</airsync:SyncKey>
            <airsync:CollectionId>5</airsync:CollectionId>
        </airsync:Collection>
    </airsync:Collections>
</airsync:Sync>
```

And i am getting response

```
<Sync xmlns="AirSync">
    <Status xmlns="AirSync">12</Status>
</Sync>
```

So i am not sure what's wrong with my request. Also i am not able to understand Status = 12.

EDIT :
Okay i found that status 12 means "The folder hierarchy has changed." and needs to perform foldersync command then retry. I did the same but everytime i am getting same response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i was passing different DeviceId for foldersync & sync request. It was my mistake.